# How to change the size of the texture when displayed it on the screen in openGL (version> 3.3)?

Tags: c++, opengl

How i can change size of texture on the screen? I'm want make a  little 2d game for learning in OpenGL.:-) I try to change vertices[] geometry, but texture doesn't stretch to it. I use something like this code:

```
 tempz = IMG_Load("graphics/menu_start.png");

    SDL_InvertSurface(tempz);

    //setup quad geometry
        //setup quad vertices
        vertices[0] = Vector2D(0.0,0.0);
        vertices[1] = Vector2D(1.0,0.0);
        vertices[2] = Vector2D(1.0,1.0);
        vertices[3] = Vector2D(0.0,1.0);

        //fill quad indices array
        GLushort* id = &indices[0];
        *id++ =0;
        *id++ =1;
        *id++ =2;
        *id++ =0;
        *id++ =2;
        *id++ =3;

        //setup quad vao and vbo stuff
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &vaoID);
        glGenBuffers(1, &vboVerticesID);
        glGenBuffers(1, &vboIndicesID);

        glBindVertexArray(vaoID);

        glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboVerticesID);
            //pass quad vertices to buffer object
            glBufferData (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

            //enable vertex attribute array for position
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
            glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,0,0);

            //pass quad indices to element array buffer
            glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboIndicesID);
            glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), &indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);



        int texture_width = 0, texture_height = 0, channels=0;

        texture_width = tempz->w;
        texture_height = tempz->h;



    //setup OpenGL texture and bind to texture unit 0
        glGenTextures(1, &textureID);
            glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
            //set texture parameters
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);


            //allocate texture 
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, texture_width, texture_height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, tempz->pixels);


        programID = LoadShaders( "shaders/shader.vert", "shaders/shader.frag" );

        glUseProgram(programID);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you posted the rest, e.g. the shaders, but what I find strange is that you have no texture coordinates in your vertices. Usually they'd be (0,0), (0,1), (1,0) and (1,1) at the corners. These are attributes in your vertices just like the physical positions. Then you can wobble the physical position all over the place and still see the texture mapped the same way over the face.

Comment: Ok I have found texture coords in shader